# Using "extends" and "depends_on" together on an EC2 instance

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to run an application on an AWS EC2 instance. I am using an LINUX/UNIX platform and a T2 micro instance type. I cloned the git repository of the application and when I try to run the .yaml file using the docker-compose (version up-to-date and supported), I get an error

> service "ingress" can't be used with `extends` as it declare `depends_on`

How to resolve this?

When I followed the instructions mentioned in the git documentation, it was for docker-desktop and everything went well. There wasn't an issue with it as above. Is it because I am doing it on a cloud?
what the problem could be?

Comment: The error have nothing to do with AWS. The configuration must be wrong. edit your question and include the compose file so we'll have some information. `extends` used for extending services from another compose files, check your tree and ensure the file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called out in the [Compose Specification definition of `extends`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/05-services/#restrictions):

> Services that have dependencies on other services cannot be used as a base. Therefore, any key that introduces a dependency on another service is incompatible with `extends`.  The non-exhaustive list of such keys is: [...] `depends_on`.

This has nothing to do with your cloud environment or the very small EC2 instance type; Docker doesn't really know anything about these and the EC2 instance looks like a normal Linux host.

It's also possible earlier versions of Compose didn't have this restriction.  The [Compose File v2](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#extends) format didn't document a restriction like this, and if you were previously using version 1 of the Compose tool, that might have caused it to work on one system but not the other.